# Replace %20 in Url with - in C#.net web.config

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, url-rewriting

I am trying to rewrite the url in C#.net framework=4.0 and visual studio version 2010, I have written following line of code in web.config file, but its not affecting the url. I want to replace the %20 in url with "-"

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="Myrule">
      <match url="(.)\ (.)" />
      <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:0}-{R:1}" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

In Chrome it shows %20 and in Mozilla it shows " " space, how do I replace the space with dash "-"?

Comment: Why you don't use encoding and decoding. See the Decode Url link. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6196h3wt.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE:**

I think the only solution for your problem is to write your own Rewrite Module. These article might help:

http://www.upperstrata.com/insights/2010-02-26/using-iis7-url-rewrite-module-with-asp-net-routing/

http://www.jphellemons.nl/post/URL-rewrite-with-aspnet-40-and-IIS7.aspx

I cannot test it and I'm not if it works that way, but try it with another regular expression:

```
((%20)|\ )+
```

For example an Url like this `http://www.goo%20le.de / hfdhdhdhd` should be replaced to this `http://www.goo-le.de-/-hfdhdhdhd`

Update:

It works in the regular expression tester http://regexpal.com/

[image]

Comment: hey @Kai can you plz tell me what will be action type? <match url="((%20)|\ )+" /> <action type=???? />

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try following [this tutorial](http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/developing-a-custom-rewrite-provider-for-url-rewrite-module) to try developing your own custom rewrite provider.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out, Hope this will work.

```
<%# Server.UrlDecode("www.stack%20overflow.com").Replace("%20", "-") %>
```