# IIS rewrite module - Encoded space at end of URL, looking for a rewrite rule to redirect the page

Tags: c#, regex, asp.net-mvc-3, url-rewrite-module

I have a pesky little problem. I am using MVC 3 with rewrite module. There is a link to my website from another website linking to mysite as:

hxxp:www.mysite.com/%20

i.e. the other site ads %20 (encoded space character) to the end of their url.

Now I need to redirect this link to the main site like so:

hxxp://www.mysite.com/

as otherwise it gives a 404 not found error.

Now the issue I have tried different rewrite rules but nothing seems to redirect  the website e.g.

```
<rule name="redirect space" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="^hxxp://www.mysite.com/%20" />
          <action type="Redirect" url="hxxp://www.mysite.com/" redirectType="Permanent" />
        </rule>
```

and many other combinations, but nothing seems to fix it and it gives 404 errors in every case.

Comment: Pretty sure match rules are regex which means your example is invalid. Does this work: `^hxxp:\/\/www\.mysite\.com\/%20`?

Comment: Replace `<match url="^hxxp://www.mysite.com/%20" />` with `<match url="^%20" />`

Comment: Tried both: ^hxxp:\/\/www\.mysite\.com\/%20 and 

<match url="^%20" /> 

but still not working.

Comment: I think the rewrite engine considers %20 as space so maybe use a regex for a space?

Comment: How about `<match url="^ $" />`?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add some variants for the space: encoded one, decoded, and a space character, like this:

```
<rule name="redirect space" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="^hxxp://www.mysite.com/((%20)|\ |\s)+" />
  <action type="Redirect" url="hxxp://www.mysite.com/" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
```

More information can be found here:

- [Using the URL Rewrite Module](http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-the-url-rewrite-module)
- [ASP.NET MVC and the new IIS7 Rewrite Module](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ASPNETMVCAndTheNewIIS7RewriteModule.aspx)
- [Creating Rewrite Rules for the URL Rewrite Module](http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/creating-rewrite-rules-for-the-url-rewrite-module)
- [Developing Rule Template for URL Rewrite Module](http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/developing-rule-template-for-url-rewrite-module)

If this still isn't working, you have to write your own rewite module. You can see here a bit more details:

[Replace %20 in Url with - in C#.net web.config](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16456671/213550)